# Python Pandas DataFrame, find longest and top recurrent sequences of elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I've got the following Pandas Dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        'chain':[['x','x','L','U','C','K'],
                 ['x','x','D','U','N','E'],
                 ['L','U','C','K','x','x'],
                 ['x','x','D','U','N','E'],
                 ['D','U','N','E','x','x'],
                 ['A','B','C','D','x','x'],
                 ['x','A','B','C','D','x'],
                 ['x','L','U','C','K','x'],
                 ['x','x','D','U','N','E']]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

How can I list the top recurrent sequences of n elements?

For n=4 we would find:

- 'D','U','N','E'  x5
- 'L','U','C','K'  x4
- 'A','B','C','D'  x2

I've began writing a monster of intricated FOR, but I think there must be a smarter way, a nice python library that I haven't found.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: Please provide some expected output

Comment: what is `n`? Also, where/How did you "find" 5 DUNE and 4 LUCK in your example?

Answer (score 1):

The data used is below:

```
data = {'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    'chain':[['A','A','L','U','C','K'],
             ['G','X','D','U','N','E'],
             ['L','U','C','K','X','B'],
             ['A','N','D','U','N','E'],
             ['D','U','N','E','C','P'],
             ['D','X','N','E','C','D'],
             ['C','A','A','A','A','B'],
             ['X','L','U','C','K','E'],
             ['X','A','D','U','N','E']]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)

                chain  id
0  [A, A, L, U, C, K]   1
1  [G, X, D, U, N, E]   2
2  [L, U, C, K, X, B]   3
3  [A, N, D, U, N, E]   4
4  [D, U, N, E, C, P]   5
5  [D, X, N, E, C, D]   6
6  [C, A, A, A, A, B]   7
7  [X, L, U, C, K, E]   8
8  [X, A, D, U, N, E]   9
```

**Solution:**

From what I understand you want combinations and then value counts:

```
from itertools import combinations
n = 4
pd.concat((pd.Series(combinations(i,n)).drop_duplicates() 
                    for i in df['chain'])).value_counts()
```

---

```
(D, U, N, E)    4
(L, U, C, K)    3
(X, D, N, E)    2
(X, D, U, N)    2
(A, U, N, E)    2
               ..
(X, N, E, C)    1
(N, D, U, E)    1
(D, X, E, D)    1
(X, L, K, E)    1
(G, D, U, N)    1
Length: 106, dtype: int64
```

For getting the top 2 combinations do:

```
s = pd.concat((pd.Series(combinations(i,n)).drop_duplicates() 
                for i in df['chain'])).value_counts().head(2)
print(s)

(D, U, N, E)    4
(L, U, C, K)    3
dtype: int64
```

Note you can `','join()` then if you want to get strings from tuple.

Comment: Thanks, it looks promising !
It works for n=4, but if I switch to n=3 it will show results which are not in the dataset (D,N,E) and n=5 is wrong in the counter.

Comment: @Vincent for n=4 , dont you think `xDUN` and `xxDU` also repeats 3 times should we consider them?

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no idea if this is what you're looking for, but based on your provided information & expected output, I worked out the below.

```
>>> df['chain'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str,x))).replace(r'\,?x\,?','',regex=True).value_counts()


D,U,N,E    4
L,U,C,K    3
A,B,C,D    2
```